# Ball sliding along a lemniscate curve takes the same time to arrive at a given point as a ball that takes the direct path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, variational-calculus

I was charmed by the following [animation](https://twitter.com/i/status/1241861318421786624). How can this problem be formulated mathematically (equation describing the motion)? How can the variational calculus be applied to find the [lemniscate curve](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html) as (unique?) solution?

Comment: The Lemniscate path can obtain with parametric equations thus you have $x(\lambda)$ and $y(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the generalized coordinate. From hier you can obtain the kinetic energy and the potential energy which is $U=-m g y(\lambda)$ and get the equation of motion

Answer (score 1):

**Lemniscate**

the Lemniscate  curve can described by this equations:

$$\vec{R}=\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {a\cos \left( \lambda \right) }{1+
 \left( \sin \left( \lambda \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
\\{\frac {a\cos \left( \lambda \right) \sin \left( 
\lambda \right) }{1+ \left( \sin \left( \lambda \right)  \right) ^{2}}
}\end {array} \right] 
$$

where $\lambda$ is the curve parameter $0\le \lambda\le 2\pi$

[image]

to blue path is the path that we want to simulate.

Start point $x=0\,,y=0$ thus: $\lambda_s=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and end point is where the tangent on Lemniscate  curve equal zero,thus $\lambda_e=-\arctan \left( 1/6\,\sqrt {3}\sqrt {6} \right) +\pi$

**The equation of motion:**

**Kinetic Energy**

$$T=\frac{m}{2}\,\vec{v}^T\,\vec{v}$$

where :

$$\vec{v}=\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial\lambda}\dot{\lambda}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -{\frac { \left( 2+ \left( \cos \left(
\lambda \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) a\sin \left( \lambda \right)
\dot{\lambda}}{4-4\, \left( \cos \left( \lambda \right)  \right) ^{2}+
 \left( \cos \left( \lambda \right)  \right) ^{4}}}
\\ {\frac { \left( 3\, \left( \cos \left( \lambda
 \right)  \right) ^{2}-2 \right) a\,\dot{\lambda}}{4-4\, \left( \cos \left(
\lambda \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( \cos \left( \lambda \right)
 \right) ^{4}}}\end {array} \right]$$

**Potential Energy**

$$U=m\,g\,y$$

thus you get the EOM:

$$\frac{d^2\,\lambda(\tau)}{d\tau^2}-3\,{\frac {g \left( \cos \left( \lambda \left( \tau \right)  \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}{a \left(  \left( \cos \left( \lambda \left( \tau
 \right)  \right)  \right) ^{2}-2 \right) }}+{\frac { \left( {\frac {d
}{d\tau}}\lambda \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \lambda
 \left( \tau \right)  \right) \cos \left( \lambda \left( \tau \right) 
 \right) }{ \left( \cos \left( \lambda \left( \tau \right)  \right) 
 \right) ^{2}-2}}+2\,{\frac {g}{a \left(  \left( \cos \left( \lambda
 \left( \tau \right)  \right)  \right) ^{2}-2 \right) }}
=0$$

**Numerical simulation:**

with $a=1$ and the initial conditions 
$\lambda(0)=\lambda_s\,,D(\lambda)(0)=0$.

the numerical simulation give you $\lambda(\tau)$

-you stop the simulation at the event $\lambda(\tau)=\lambda_e$ and get the time $\tau_e$ that take a ball to slide  on the Lemniscate path.

Results

[image]

- "Ball silde time" on Lemniscate path  $0.46 [s]$
- "Ball silde time" on $y=0.5\,x$ path  $0.59 [s]$
- "Ball silde time" on $y=\,x$    path  $0.37 [s]$